# ActiveRecord::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, attributes

I want to create a new "AnswerStat" object and save it in the database. I am getting:

```
can't write unknown attribute `answer_stat_id'

app/models/answer_stat.rb:14:in `new'
app/models/answer_stat.rb:14:in `add_answer'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:31:in `block in index'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:30:in `each'
```

answer_stat_id does not exist, it refers I guess to the primary key of the table answer_stats which is id. I do not explicitly declare this attribute of course. Why is Rails looking for this inexistent attribute? Code:

```
class AnswerStat < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :contact, :statement, :answer_sum, :answer_count, :variation

  belongs_to :contact, :class_name => "Friend"
  has_one :statement

  validates_uniqueness_of :contact, :scope => :statement

  def self.add_answer(answer)
    if stat = AnswerStat.find_by_contact_id_and_statement_id(answer.contact.id, answer.statement.id)
    ...........do some stuff...........
    else
      @answer_stat = AnswerStat.new(:contact => answer.contact, :statement => answer.statement, :answer_count => 1, :answer_sum => answer.description, :variation => answer.description)
      @answer_stat.save
    end      
  end
```

I am calling it from the rails console, or from any controller, using:

```
   Answer.all.each do |a|
      AnswerStat.add_answer(a)
   end
```

The answer_stats table (sqlite3 using PRAGME table_info(answer_stats)):

```
0|id|INTEGER|1||1
1|contact_id|integer|0||0
2|answer_sum|integer|0||0
3|answer_count|integer|0||0
4|created_at|datetime|1||0
5|updated_at|datetime|1||0
6|statement_id|integer|0||0
7|variation|integer|0||0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the table for `AnswerStat` looking like? Also, which line causes the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it could come from the `statement` attribute, which refers to an associated model.I think [it's looking for an answer_stat_id foreign key](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one) in the statements table.

You should either :

- [create the associated answer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference) via `@answer_stat.build_statement(...)`
- redesign your model associations if the statement is meant to preexist the stat

Comment: The need to redesign associations is probably excessive. Assuming both are created at once, you just need to do it right in code. But indeed, it looks like a column is missing from `statements`.

Comment: right, my mistake. What i wanted to say is that the nature of the association was probably not clearly understood.

Comment: Indeed, probably typical beginner mistake.

Comment: you were right. answer_stats belongs to statement, not the other way around. Indeed a beginner's mistake. Thanks a lot.